# Go Lint only check new test diff files (Perforce)

Tags: go, lint, golint

I have a go linter in a `.golangci.yml` file for my workspace. As of now, I have disabled lints in test files since there are simply too many checks:

```
run:

  tests: false
  # rest of run configs ...

issues:
  # all run issues
```

However, I want to enable lint checks only on *new* test files, or new *diffs*. Any existing linting errors should be ignored.

I tried modifying the yml file using a `new : true` parameter under `issues`:

```
run:

  tests: false
  # rest of run configs ...

issues:
  new : true
  # all run issues
```

However, the linter still checks *all* test files for listing, including the previous problems.

I tried switching the order and also replacing `new : true`  with `max-same-issues : 0`.

I was in particular following this guide: https://golangci-lint.run/usage/configuration/.

It's also worth noting that the SVC is Perforce, not Git.